# Always getting Run Time Error #Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I'm getting run time error always when I tried to login. Below is the code. I'm using Java `JRE 8 Eclipse` to compile it. Can anyone please let me know what's the problem? I've omitted most of the code. Link to full code : https://codeshare.io/5gNyZw . Already tried Removal of JDBC ODBC bridge in java 8 and how to use JDBC in java 8 but nothing works

```
try
{
    String database="StegoKeys.mdb";
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + database + ";PWD=cegospdv";
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    String sql="select * from keys";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
       if(txtKey.getText().equals(rs.getString("key")))
           {
            id=rs.getString("uname");
            if(txtname.getText().equals(id))
            {
                int stat=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("status"));
                flag=1;
                if(stat==1)
                {
                      button1.setEnabled(true);
                      button2.setEnabled(true);
                      btnadminset.setVisible(true);
                      txtKey.setEnabled(false);
                      btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
                }                   
                else
                {
                      button1.setEnabled(true);
                      txtname.setEnabled(false);
                      txtKey.setEnabled(false);
                      btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(id+" in MainStego");
            con.close();
            break;
        }               
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid User & Key");
    }
   }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Run Time Error");
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add the stack trace to your question

Comment: I'm getting the run time error as mention in the catch block